# how to fill polygons with gradient color in google maps javascript api v3

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, polygon, gradient

i have drawn a polygon  using the  code below

```
    var triangleCoords = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.80071485890158, -122.45498657226562),
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.75621226898872, -122.45292663574219),
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.73177873209313, -122.42889404296875),
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.73992414059749, -122.37808227539062),
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.80993765238262, -122.40348815917969)
    ];

    bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: triangleCoords,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#334433',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
    bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

but  i want to fill polygon with gradient rather  than a single  color.how can i do it?

Comment: It's not supported by the API.

Comment: It has been 4+ years, is this still not supported by Google Maps API?

Answer (score 1):

That is not currently supported by the API. The listed properties for styling the [Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Polygon) object are:

- fillColor
- fillOpacity
- strokeColor
- strokeOpacity
- strokePosition
- strokeWeight

Since there is only a single fillColor, the inner color is solid (ie, none patterned or gradient).

Comment: is it supported in bing maps